Create new columns and assign their values from existing column's values
I have a Dataset downloaded from Kaggle for my project, I would like to create new columns and assign their values based on an existing column.
My actual Dataset is complicated, I will give a similar but simpler dataset for easy discussion.
Input:
Month  | Fruit  | Weight
------- -------- --------
1-2020 | Orange | 0.2
1-2020 | Kiwi   | 0.9
2-2020 | Orange | 2.1
2-2020 | Kiwi   | 1.4
...... | .....  | ...

To be able to create a required line chart, I need to change this Dataset structure, making Orange, Kiwi new columns with Weight values, so that Month is not repeated.
Desired output:
Month  | Orange | Kiwi
------- -------- ------
1-2020 | 0.2    | 0.9
2-2020 | 2.1    | 1.4


This presumes that the combination of Month and Fruit is unique for each record in the original dataframe? Or do you expect the operation to sum the weights of duplicate keys?

The basic thing you're looking for is a pivot:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Month': ['1-2020', '1-2020', '2-2020', '2-2020'],
    'Fruit': ['Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Orange', 'Kiwi'],
    'Weight': [0.2, 0.9, 2.1, 1.4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Fruit', values='Weight')

print(pivot_df)

Output:
Fruit   Kiwi  Orange
Month               
1-2020   0.9     0.2
2-2020   1.4     2.1

If you want Month as a column instead of the index:
pivot_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pivot_df.columns.name = None

print(pivot_df)

Output:
    Month  Kiwi  Orange
0  1-2020   0.9     0.2
1  2-2020   1.4     2.1

If there are duplicate combinations of Month and Fruit in the original data, and you want to sum them (for example):
data = {
    'Month': ['1-2020', '1-2020', '1-2020', '2-2020', '2-2020'],
    'Fruit': ['Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi', 'Orange', 'Kiwi'],
    'Weight': [0.2, 0.9, 1.1, 2.1, 1.4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Fruit', values='Weight', aggfunc='sum')
print(pivot_df)

Output:
Fruit   Kiwi  Orange
Month               
1-2020   2.0     0.2
2-2020   1.4     2.1


Thank you so much! I've been looking for this! I'm going to do more research to know more about pivot table. Thank you!!!
